# Is there a way to trigger a selenium program remotely? (Like from my phone or from another laptop

Tags: python, selenium

I made a selenium script that would go to a website and buy a certain product that is currently out of stock. I have an email alert that I would get when the product goes back in stock, however when I receive the email I will probably not be at the computer with the script.

What would be the simplest way to run the program from my phone. Would it be to set up a remote desktop to access my computer from my phone? Also, everything would still run correctly if the monitor was off and if the selenium window was in the background, correct?

Comment: Yes, as long as computer is on selenium will run, should not matter as long as it is only monitor that is off.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do to make the entire process automated is link the email alert to your program, when the email comes in it will trigger the program to visit the webpage and automatically buy the item.

I am assuming everything is already saved payment information and other important info etc., and just keeping the programming running in the background on a computer at all times.

I would obviously encourage this to be hard wired with an ethernet cord too, if there is an issue or someone disconnects your WiFi and you miss the item.

Have fun!